# Notification PendingIntent from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

guys.

I've been debugging this for days, but I can't find an answer for this.

As the title says, I am using `BroadcastReceiver` to make my notification.

Everything was fine until I add `.addAction`.

It needs `PendingIntent` for default and I made a `PendingIntent`.

But the problem is this; when I add `.addAction`, It says this

```
Incompatiable types.

Required : android.app.Notification

Found : android.app.Notification.Builder
```

the code works perfectly fine with out the `.addAction` and the `PendingIntent`.

What could be the problem?

Here is my code,

- `BroadcastReceiver`, `WifiService.java`

  ```
  Intent intent = new Intent(mcontext, MainActivity.class);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mcontext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

  Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(mcontext)
          .setContentTitle("Welcome home!")
          .setContentText("You have a to-do; " + hometodo)
          .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.home_light)
          .setLargeIcon(icon)
          .setLights(0xFFFFD800, 5000, 0)
          .addAction(R.drawable.archive_notification, "Mark as done", pIntent);
          //.addAction gets the error.
          .build();

  NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mcontext.getSystemService(mcontext.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

  notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
  ```

Comment: `.addAction(R.drawable.archive_notification, "Mark as done", pIntent);` remove `;`

Comment: I feel so dumb ;( Thanks..

Comment: no prob, your welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

used `NotificationCompat` for setting `.addAction(...)`.

Check [official docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html)

> action buttons won't appear on platforms prior to Android 4.1. Action
>   buttons depend on expanded notifications, which are only available in
>   Android 4.1 and later.

Comment: @BedrockDev just remove redundant `;`

Comment: @pskink  ya really you have an `Eagle Eye`. Thanks